# Why does typeorm create a table for a deleted class in nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am a beginner at nestjs building a small back end app. I had initially defined a user class which led to the creation of a table called user. I have subsequently deleted all those files and created a new class called people.
Now, when I run my code nestjs creates 2 tables - user and people.
The code is working correctly in that the people table is populated correctly.
How do I get it to stop creating the other table?

Comment: I've had to manually remove old tables when I change the names.

Answer (score 6):

Remove your dist and restart your server. More than likely something was incorrectly cached.

Comment: To add to this, TypeORM doesn't preserve a state so you'll have to manually remove tables.